# Not speaking between Shemoneh Esrei and Hallel

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, hefsek-interruption, speech-talking, hallel

On a day when Hallel is recited (for example Rosh Chodesh) I've heard that one should not (lichatchila) speak between Shemoneh Esrei and Hallel. Rather, as soon as the chazzon finishes chazaras ha'shatz (repetition of the Shemoneh Esrei), he and the congregation should start reciting Hallel.

Is there such an opinion? What is the source for this? Who are the poskim that discuss this? Are there other opinions (that hold one may speak out)? Is there a difference depending on what the person wants to say?

Comment: This would make sense since there is no Kaddish in between them to designate them as separate parts of the service.

Answer (score 4):

Per [Shaalos U'teshuvos Maharsham 1:1 - paragraph 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1386&st=&pgnum=14) Tosefta Menachos Perek 6 - says that Tefila and Hallel are Meakev each other, that one is not Yotzei Tefila until you say Hallel. However at the end of the paragraph he says that based on the Perisha 122 the main prohibition of interruption is only on the Shaliach Tzibur. It seems to me that based on this the maharsham has no issue with a person talking between Tefila and Hallel.

Comment: I haven't read the responsum inside yet, but that sounds like a really novel read of the Tosefta. How does he explain the word שבח in the Tosefta? [6:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/f/f52.htm)

Comment: Hmmmm it seems he just ignores that word. Not impressed, especially because שבח is attested to in old manuscripts of the Tosefta. He even says he hasn't looked at any commentaries on the Tosefta.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer, please, to clarify whether the _Maharsham_ says not to interrupt between _t'fila_ and _halel_, or merely that they're _m'akev_ one another?

Comment: See Igros Moshe (OC, 3:70), Chazon Yehezkel (Tosefta ibid), Mikraei Kodesh (Sukkos 2:22) that Tosefta is referring to the 3 parts of Shmoneh Esrai.

Comment: @Yoni - See also Or Sameach intro to Hilchos Tefilla who reads the Tosefta this way